# Security namespace does not support custom security filters

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

A am trying to setup a spring security namespace for jboss, but every time I try to start the server, I get the error

> Security namespace does not support decoration of element
>   [filter-chain]

Here is the code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<bean xml:id="customSecurityFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
<security:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
<security:filter-chain pattern="/MaintenanceLogin.jsp*" filters="none"/>
<security:filter-chain pattern="/PortalLogin.jsp*" filters="none"/>
</bean>

<security:http>
    <security:custom-filter ref="customSecurityFilter" before="FIRST"/>
    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                        default-target-url="/DisplayAlerts.action" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />     
</security:http>
```

Please help

Comment: Just add multiple `<security:http />` elements instead of `filter-chain`s. Add `<security:http pattern="/login.jsp" security="none" />` or simply allow all access to those URLs by specifiying `<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />`. You are making it too complex.

Comment: Doing either of these results in a `Security namespace does not support decoration of element [filter-chain]` error

Comment: You have to remove the custom filter of course...

Comment: I can't just remove it. The custom filter has to be there to allow access to the login pages without having to be logged in first.

Comment: Yes you can... That is the whole point of the configuration I told you to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use filter-chain you can wrap it in a map

```
<bean xml:id="customSecurityFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
 <security:filter-chain-map path-type="regex">
    <security:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
    <security:filter-chain pattern="/MaintenanceLogin.jsp*" filters="none"/>
    <security:filter-chain pattern="/PortalLogin.jsp*" filters="none"/>
 </security:filter-chain-map path-type="regex">
</bean>
```

you can refer the doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)